# Why texture object changes in QOpenglWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have 9 texture objects, each texture object bind to a texture unit like this:

```
QOpenglWidget::initializeGL(){
    ...
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glGenTextures(1, &tbo0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, tbo0);
    glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, GL_R32F, 100, 100, 32);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glGenTextures(1, &tbo1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, tbo1);
    glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, GL_R32F, 100, 100, 32);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE2);
    glGenTextures(1, &tbo2);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tbo2);
    glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,1,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16,TEXTURE_SIZE_LIMIT ,TEXTURE_SIZE_LIMIT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_NONE);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE3);
    glGenTextures(1, &tbo3);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tbo3);
    glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,1,GL_RGBA16F,TEXTURE_SIZE_LIMIT,TEXTURE_SIZE_LIMIT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &frame1);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frame1);
    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, tbo2, 0);
    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, tbo3, 0);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, defaultFramebufferObject());

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE4);
    glGenTextures(1,&tbo4);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tbo4);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA16F,20,20,0,GL_RGBA,GL_FLOAT,NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE5);
    glGenTextures(1,&tbo5);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tbo5);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA16F,20,20,0,GL_RGBA,GL_FLOAT,NULL);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &frame2);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frame2);
    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, tbo5, 0);
    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, tbo4, 0);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, defaultFramebufferObject());

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE6);
    glGenTextures(1, &tbo6);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tbo6);
    glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 14, GL_RGBA16F, TEXTURE_SIZE_LIMIT, TEXTURE_SIZE_LIMIT * 2);//TEXTURE_SIZE_LIMIT == 4096
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 14);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE7);
    glGenTextures(1, &tbo7);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tbo7);
    glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 14, GL_RGBA16F, TEXTURE_SIZE_LIMIT, TEXTURE_SIZE_LIMIT * 2);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 14);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE8);
    glGenTextures(1, &tbo8);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tbo8);
    glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 14, GL_RGBA16F, TEXTURE_SIZE_LIMIT, TEXTURE_SIZE_LIMIT * 2);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 14);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    GLint whichID;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D, &whichID);

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &frame3);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frame3);
    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, tbo6, 0);
    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, tbo7, 0);
    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, tbo8, 0);
    ...
}
```

then I check texture object name in `QOpenglWidget::paintGL()` and `QOpenglWidget::resizeGL()` like this:

```
QOpenglWidget::paintGL(){
    ...
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE8);
    GLint whichID;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D, &whichID);
}

QOpenglWidget::resizeGL(int width , int height){
    glViewport(0,0,width,height);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE8);
    GLint whichID;
    glGetIntegerv(GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D, &whichID);
    ...
}
```

I find that `whichID` will be 9 which is `tbo8` in `initializeGL`,but 0 after `resizeGL` and `paintGL`. `tbo0` to `tbo7` behavior correctly. If I rebind `tbo8` to `GL_TEXTURE8` in `paintGL`, `whichID` will always be 9 which is correct. Why just `tbo8` changes after `initializeGL`?